# Fedora unable to mount nfs due to firewalld

Tags: networking, fedora, nfs, qemu, firewalld

I am trying to create a nfs to share between my host and guest VM (run with `qemu-kvm`).
I followed [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS#Installation) ad this is the situation:

```
host:
cat /etc/exports
/mnt/nfsshare   192.168.122.76/24(rw,sync,all_squash,nohide,anonuid=0,anongid=0)

firewall-cmd --list-all 
FedoraWorkstation (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: tun0 wlp0s20f3
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns mountd nfs rpc-bind samba-client ssh
  ports: 1025-65535/udp 1025-65535/tcp 892/tcp 111/tcp 111/udp 2049/tcp 2049/udp 875/udp 875/tcp 32803/tcp 32769/udp 892/udp 662/tcp 662/udp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

rpcinfo -p 192.168.122.76
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100005    1   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  20048  mountd
    100005    2   udp  20048  mountd
    100024    1   udp  35373  status
    100005    2   tcp  20048  mountd
    100024    1   tcp  40085  status
    100005    3   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  20048  mountd
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100021    1   udp  44060  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  44060  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  44060  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  37147  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  37147  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  37147  nlockmgr
```

However, when I boot the guest and mount with
`mount -t nfs 192.168.122.1:/mnt/nfsshare /mnt/nfsshare_client`, it just hangs.

If I disable the host firewall with `systemctl stop firewalld` it works, but strangely the VM has no internet connection anymore, I can't even ping google.

The relevant command to run the VM is: `-nic bridge,br=virbr0,helper=/usr/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper`, which is used for internet connection.

I know that there are a lot of very similar questions, but I cannot find one that applies my case. I added all possible firewalld exceptions and it still does not work.

Any help is appreciated.